# Enlarge sizing handle of a Rectangle in a Windows Desktop App for touch-screen ease of use

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm working on a Windows desktop app in C#/XAML and I have a "Crop image" feature using a Rectangle. But when using the app on a touch screen, the sizing handles in the corners are really hard to catch for the user. Is there a way to enlarge those handles in order to resize the rectangle with ease using a finger or stylus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about enlarging the handle, however, you can probably achieve the desired effect as follows (in broad strokes):

- set up an event handler on the image to capture mouse activity
- when a mouse event occurs, calculate which corner of the rectangle is closest to the event X & Y coordinates
- update the rectangle accordingly

I think this should be pretty straight-forward but feel free to leave a comment if you need further clarification.